# Jquery plugin to work on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I've been developing a simple plugin for jquery, I have managed to get it to work perfectly for singular elements but I can't get it to work for use on more than one element on a page.

How do I construct the function to work on multiple elements?

Here's my construct, its really basic.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluginName= function(prop){

    var params = $.extend({
// param default set here

    },prop);

// functions added here

    return this;    
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This works fine for a singular use on page but if I wanted to make this work for multiple elements how would I do that?

The function is meant to change input fields so would need to work for multiple instances on a page.

I tried adding a `this.each(function(){ ... })` to wrap around main content but this returned the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not sure where to go with this and other tutorials will make me strip out the entire code and start again.

Thanks

EDIT

I've edited my code, I can not get the function to call through.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.colorChange= function(params){
        var defaults= {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        };

        var params = $.extend(defaults, params);

        return this.each(function(){

        changeColor();

            function changeColor(defaults){
            $(this).css({
                'background-color' : defaults.backgroundColor
            });
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

If I don't wrap this in a function and just create it as an anonymous function it works fine. However I intend to have many functions and the code could get a bit sloppy.

For some reason this is not working, any help?

Comment: Actually, `this.each` _is_ the proper way to do what you want. You should've shown the code called on `this` in your question.

Comment: Can you post concrete sample about your issue?

Comment: I've made a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb907s24/) to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to instantiate an instance of your class/function for each matching element. The top level `each` goes just inside the `$.fn.plugginName= function(prop){`